# How to get dynamic input from user with out form using Java servlet?

Tags: java, webservice-client

Please help me to achieve the below requirement.
I need to pass a parameter in the URL which dynamically get the value from user and fetch the record the select statement or the procedure.

I tried with the hard coded value,I don't know how to pass the variable in it.

Below is the code for your reference.

```
package notifprj;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import notifprj.ConnectionUtils;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import oracle.jdbc.OracleTypes;
@WebServlet(name = "DispNotif", urlPatterns = { "/dispnotif" })
public class DispNotif extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String CONTENT_TYPE = "text/html; charset=windows-1252";
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        super.init(config);
    }
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE);
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<html><body>");
        ResultSet rs = null;
       Connection conn =null;
    try {
         conn = ConnectionUtils.getConnection();
         Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");


           String strQry="{call getUserDetails(?,?)}";
        CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall(strQry);

        cs.setString(1,"CHRISTIAN.MEDINA");
        cs.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);         
        cs.execute();
           // get cursor and cast it to ResultSet
          rs = (ResultSet) cs.getObject(2);

           out.println("<table border=1 width=50% height=30% align=center>");
           out.println("<tr><th>NOTIFICATION_ID</th><th>SUBJECT</th><th>AMOUNT</th><th>CURRENCY</th><tr>");


           // loop it like normal
           while (rs.next()) {
                   String NotifID = rs.getString("NOTIFICATION_ID");
                   String Subject = rs.getString("SUBJECT");
                   String Amount = rs.getString("AMOUNT");
                   String Currency = rs.getString("CURRENCY");
               out.println("<tr><td>" + NotifID + "</td><td>" + Subject + "</td><td>" + Amount + "</td><td>" + Currency + "</td></tr>"); 
           }                       

        out.println("</table>");
        out.println("</html></body>");
        conn.close();
       }
        catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        out.println("error");
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just retrieve the value of the parameter with `request.getParameter("userName")` :

```
cs.setString(1,request.getParameter("userName"));
```